# Show that $H_0^1(\Omega) \cap L^p(\Omega)$ is a Banach space

Tags: proof-verification, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

> Let be $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set and $E = H_0^1(\Omega) \cap L^p(\Omega)$ with $1 \leq p < \infty$ provided with the norm $||u||_E = ||u||_{H_0^1(\Omega)} + ||u||_{L^p(\Omega)}$. Show that $(E,||\cdot||_E)$ is a Banach space.

I would like to know if my attempt is right.

> $\textbf{My attempt:}$
>
> Let be $(\varphi_m) \subset E$ a Cauchy sequence, then there are $u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $v \in L^p(\Omega)$ such that $||u - \varphi_m||_{H_0^1(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0$ and $||v - \varphi_m||_{L^p(\Omega)} \rightarrow 0$. These functions are in $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ because $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $v \in L^p(\Omega)$. We only need to show that $||u - v||_{L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)} = 0$ to ensure $u \in E$, but this occurs because
>
> $\begin{align*}
> 0 &\leq ||u - v||_{L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)}\\
> &\leq ||u - \varphi_m||_{L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)} + ||\varphi_m - v||_{L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)}\\
> &\overset{m \rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow} 0,
> \end{align*}$
>
> where this convergence is true from the convergences previous and because $L^p(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$. $\square$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the norm on $L^1_{\rm loc}(\Omega)$? You should better prove that $\|u-v\|_{L^1(K)}=0$ for every compact subset $K\subset\Omega$. Then, of course, $u=v$ follows.

Comment: $||f|| = \int_K |f| dx$, where $K$ is compact in $\Omega$

Comment: @George that is of course not a norm on $L^1$. :)

Comment: @hal4math, why not? I'm considering $f$ as a representative of the class $[f] = \{ f ; f \sim g \}$ ($f \sim g \iff \int_K |f| dx = \int_K |g| dx$ a.e.)

Comment: That is maybe a norm on $L^1_{loc}(K)$ but not a norm on an general $\Omega$.

Comment: @George Because if $f=0$ on $K$ but $f\neq 0$ outside of $K$, then $\|f\|=0$ but $f\neq 0$.

Comment: If I change $||\cdot||_{L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)}$ by $||\cdot||_{L_{\text{loc}}^1(K)}$ for an arbitrary $K \subset \Omega$ compact, then will my attempt be correct?

Comment: @George. I think so, yes. Though in the last step I think it would not hurt to mention that $H^1_0(\Omega)$ has also an embedding into an $L^{p^*}(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt is flawed because $L^1_{loc}$ is not a normed space. Instead take arbitrary compact $K\subset \Omega$. Then the convergence of $\phi_m$ implies 
$\|u-\phi_m\|_{L^1(K)}\to 0$ and $\|v-\phi_m\|_{L^1(K)}\to 0$.

---

Here is a different attempt without talking about $L^1_{loc}$.

We have $\phi_m \to u$ in $H^1_0$ and $\phi_m \to v$ in $L^p$. It only remains to show $u=v$.
Take $z\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Then $\phi\mapsto \int_\Omega z\phi $ is a linear and bounded functional on *both* $H^1_0$ and $L^p$. This proves
$$
\int_\Omega \phi_m z \to \int_\Omega u z
$$
and
$$
\int_\Omega \phi_m z \to \int_\Omega v z.
$$
It follows $\int_\Omega (u-v)z=$ for all $z\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. Hence $u=v$ a.e.

Comment: I think you wanted to write $H_0^1$ instead of $H^1$

Comment: Edited. Here it does not really matter whether $H^1$ or $H^1_0$ is used.